# The significance of [ContentType("HTML")] in the Visual Studio SDK

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-sdk

I am looking at the [Roslyn September 2012 CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) with Reflector, and I noticed the following:

```
[ContentType("HTML")]
[Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[Export(typeof(VenusTextViewManager))]
[TextViewRole("PRIMARYDOCUMENT")]
internal sealed class VenusTextViewManager : IVsTextViewCreationListener, IWpfTextViewCreationListener
{
    // ...
}
```

Why is `"HTML"` passed into the constructor of ContentTypeAttribute, since Roslyn is for C# and VB.NET? Is it that the HTML implies some sort of rich text formatting? Or perhaps this is to support markup for the ASP.NET Razor engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, this is for support of aspx and cshtml/vbhtml files.  We're hoping to find a better way to deal with the issues this class currently handles in a future release though.